# Getting output from one function to another, specifically an array

Tags: c#, function, methods

I am very new to c# and I am trying to get my head around functions/methods.

Below, i am trying to create a program that has one function create 200 random numbers and store them in an array, i would then like another function to sort through said array and tally up duplicates. that is where the problem comes in, i am not entirely sure how to get the array from the first function or at least the values from it into the second function. the code below may be sloppy as i was kind of half way through when i got stuck.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExamineArray();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void CreateArray(int i)
    {
        int[] array = new int[200];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i<200; i++)
        {
            int x = rand.Next(0, 11);
            array[i] = x;
        }
    }

    static void ExamineArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CreateArray(i));
        }
    }
}
```

i have thought about having the second array go through and completely rewrite the contents of the first array but i still don't know how to get the contents over. sorry for asking such a simple question.

Comment: You need to read about parameters and return type. [Here's a simple explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_method_parameters.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method can be void, which means that it does not have a return type, or it can return an object. Usually a method that is called `CreateArray` can be expected also to return that array. You have to modify the signature of your method like this:

```
static int[] CreateArray(int i){ // your method code goes in here}
```

that means it will return an array of integer. Inside the method when you have finished constructing your array use the `return` keyword to get it out:

```
static int[] CreateArray(int numberOfArrayItems)
{
    int[] array = new int[numberOfArrayItems];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfArrayItems; i++)
    {
        int x = rand.Next(0, 11);
        array[i] = x;
    }
    return array;  // <-- here you return the array
}
```

Now at the calling site of this method you can now simply harvest the constructed array for example:

```
static void ExamineArray()
{
    int[] array = CreateArray(200);
    // do what ever you want with it
}
```

If you want to read up on method signature and return types here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) and here is a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm#:%7E:text=Defining%20Methods%20in%20C%23&text=The%20return%20type%20is%20the,identifier%20declared%20in%20the%20class.)

Comment: when i enter the code:
        static int[] CreateArray(int 200)
i get an error under the 200 saying it expects a ','
any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @ChibiAyano yes, when you write the signature of the method: `static int[] CreateArray(int 200)` you need to give the parameter in the parentheses a name so that you can reference it inside the method. You don't write simply `int 200`